# How to update Tor for Vidalia?

Tags: vidalia

Simple question , im still using vidalia but since fews days im having a message that saying Tor is now obsolete .
id like to know how to get a Tor update for my vidalia bundle .
Thanks for answering .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Vidalia is deprecated.

It will not receive further updates and the vidalia bundles haven't received any in some years. If you need to update Tor, you can download a recent copy of `tor.exe` from the [Expert Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) for windows or your relevant package manager for Linux or OS X and use that with vidalia.